# Rails requiring standard Ruby libraries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I ran into an issue testing a new app in production environment.that `Net::HTTP` was not defined, but in development it was.

Naturally a `require 'net/http'` somewhere solves this (e.g. I put it in `config/application.rb` after `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`,as I understand, there is no gem name I can add to `Gemfile`).

But can I find a list of which Ruby standard modules/classes need to be required, or should I just start adding everything I need to `application.rb` to be clear (`date`, `json`, `net/http`, etc.)?

Comment: That's strange, in what kind of file?

Comment: What do you mean in what kind of file? Just any code file in `app/controllers/` or where ever, `Net::HTTP` was not defined/loaded and being production, it wont autoload things it missed.

Comment: the list of standard lib parts are [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/). It seems unnecessary to me that you'd include all of them, why not just include the ones you use in application.rb?

Comment: oh no, maybe my wording is not clear. I only want to require things I use, but I meant a list of ones Rails already promises to be required so don't have to be in application.rb explicitly (like it seems Date/Time/etc. is always there along with Rails patches/extensions, but I cant see where that is documented).

Comment: You mean `Net::HTTP` with *two* colons, right?